# How to Run a "Dot 1" File in Linux Terminal

Tags: linux, file, terminal

I need to run this file in the terminal (linux).

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ncbi-seg.1.html

It comes as a ".1" file. Any ideas?

Comment: That's just the manual. If you're on ubuntu and you want to install this program, look for a package named `ncbi-seg` in your package manager.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (it is, after all, a man-page):

```
nroff -man ncbi-seg.1 |less
```

Better, if the program is *installed* (not just a ".1" file):

```
man ncbi-seg
```

(section "1" is the default).

A comment notes that (at least on Linux), the `man` program accepts an actual pathname, e.g.,

```
man ./ncbi-seg.1
```

and referring to my followup, I made this script, `qm` in June 1995:

```
#!/bin/sh
tbl $* | nroff -man |less
```

Since then, most (not all) versions of `man` have incorporated the fix to automatically run `tbl`.

Comment: I suppose so, but `nroff -man` is more portable than nuances of `man`, and habits die hard.